# pre-flight OPTIONS request for CORS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cors

I use a middle call cors like this in development

```
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:8100'}));
```

and for every route request I start to see the 2 request:

[image]

Will this still happen in production? Is it a problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will continue to happen. No, it is not a problem, unless you create a route that conflicts with it.

The `OPTIONS` request is used by the browser to detect the CORS support of the server for that particular endpoint.

From [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):

> ...  for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on user data (in particular, for HTTP methods other than GET, or for POST usage with certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP OPTIONS request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request method.
>
> ...
>
> Unlike simple requests (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send.  Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may have implications to user data.

Comment: I'm creating an app that needs restful API, in development my app is running on localhost thus it needs cors, but in production do you think I need to setup cors in my server side?

Comment: @Jennifer You'll want to ask that as a separate question on SO.